# What is the best way to deploy printers to clients?

Tags: group-policy, network-printer, printer, print-server

What is the best practice method for deploying printers to clients using the Print Management tool on a Windows Server 2019?

There are printers based in each remote office, which I would like to deployed to the device rather than the user, so if a user from another office visits, the client will have the local office printer added.

Currently, I have the AD set up as Site > Office > Workstations. I then created a GPO linked to this OU and then deployed the printer to this GPO in Print Management.

However, the clients are not automatically installing the printers. After reading up on this, it seems that it is to do with the KB3170455 patch. So I was wondering what the best practice method is without having to use third-party tool?